# Xcode 5 non root URL repository

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, osx-mavericks

I'm using Mavericks, XCode 5.
 I want to add non root URL repository 
e.g. `svn://sources.xxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx`

I have tried it from **XCode Preferences -> Accounts**, but XCode prompts me to have only root URL (i.e. `svn://sources.xxx.com/xxx`) and I don't have access to it. I only have access to `svn://sources.xxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx`

The repository was getting added successfully in XCode 4.x, but I'm helpless for XCode 5

Does anybody have such problem?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, you can checkout your working copy using command-line SVN client and specifying the URL you want. Then add this working copy in XCode. Should work at least this way.

As well, I remember that XCode allows you to specify protocol, port, server hostname and path when working with repositories. These settings should be available in **XCode preferences | SCM**.

Comment: I'm not finding way to add working copy in XCode 5, also there are no mentioned settings in 'XCode preferences | SCM' in XCode 5.